# Stary Quotes Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, post, comments

OK so here is the deal I am using a plugin called stray quotes for a website,http://ohmsgaming.com/quotes-from-last-session/ , It has some really nice functions I can't find in other plugins like that it has a simple to add quotes to the database etc. Thing is, not only was the styling odd and I had to fix all that. But it only displays text. It doesn't allow comments for each quote, voting, or sharing. This is something I have been asked to make, and for the life of me I can't figure out how.

Here are some of my ideas:

Forget the plugin, use wordpress posts instead, make it so only that post type is shown on that page only. This allows comments to be tied in already etc. Problems here are: Styling the post, and only that type, and making it easy to add quotes for admins and users.

Other thought, modify the stray quote plugin, add the functions to allow commenting etc, since it already has the easy to add parts. Problems: Lots of code to have to read, No clue how to make it so when you hit reply it opens a new "page" with the quote and all its comments in paginated form.

So my questions:

Can anyone help me with either of the above. I have looked through tons of stuff and I can't figure out what to do, there is so many freaking things. The ideal thing would be to have a plugin like stray quotes that had a simple to add quotes section for all; stored them separately from posts; allowed comments(with pagination) and voting; and styled well.

P.S. the WordPress theme I am using is suffusion, which has tons of custom abilities.

Comment: Do you want all the quotes on one page? Where will the quotes go?

Comment: The best thing would be to display 10-15 quotes with pages for the others and each time you reply for the quote it loads that quote and the comments but with 10-15 comments and pages for the rest of the comments. By pages I mean the pagination thing I see where there is a list of pages at the bottom of the static page and when you click it is loads the new stuff in the same static page. As for where it will go, what do you mean?

Comment: If you look at the link the original post you can see how it is setup right now with stray quotes plugin. And it will make more pages if the count is above 10. So I want something like that but with the added feature of comments for each quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add quotes as a custom taxonomy.

Or simply have post entries with a category of "quote" be output with a different CSS class than normal post entry.